# How to create template-based email using API

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have some email templates defined in MyTemplates in Exact Target. From the ExactTargetUI, I can create a Template-based Emails in MyEmails.

But I am required to do it through API. Is there a way to create an Email in (Contents->MyEmail) by using a template so that I can then just load the contents in the template-based-email ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the SOAP API, there is not a way to create an Email object that is linked to a template but it would be possible to retrieve a Template object with the LayoutHTML property and use that value to create an email.  After retrieving the LayoutHTML, pass that in as the HTMLBody on an Email object.  The disadvantage of this is if there are any changes to the Template, there is not going to be an option in the UI to allow for updating the email automatically with the new template changes.